# How to tree-shake exported import?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have `my-module` with the following files:

*src/components/foo.js*

```js
export default class Foo { ... }
```

*src/components/bar.js*

```js
export default class Bar { ... }
```

*index.js*

```js
import Foo from './src/components/foo'
import Bar from './src/components/bar'

export { Foo, Bar }
```

My goal is to allow users to easily import both `Foo` and `Bar`, but not lose the ability to tree-shake one of them in case only the other one is used.

I tested the following with Webpack:

```js
import { Foo } from 'my-module'
```

I get `Foo`, but I get `Bar` in the resulting bundle as well, which shouldn't happen. The only way to prevent that seems to be by doing this instead:

```js
import Foo from 'my-module/components/foo'
```

But I don't like this very much since the user needs to know the internal directory structure of the module. Is there a way I can make the former import tree-shakable?

Comment: This happens because you import both `Foo` and `Bar` in index.js.Try to use `export { default as Foo } from './src/components/foo` for each in index.js instead, and see if you get a different result?

Answer (score 2):

This:

```js
import { Foo } from 'my-module'
```

Actually *does* work correctly and `Bar` is tree-shaken, but only if Webpack is in production mode.